# How can I use google API to remove collaborators permissions from files and folders?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm using integromat to do an http request to google drive API.

I'm working with collaborators that get access to selected google drive files and folder - usually more then one folder and a lot of files across my google drive.

My goal is to remove the collaborators google drive permissions from all of my files and folders by using the collaborator`s email address.

While trying to do it I noticed that there is a big difference between the google v2 API to google v3 API - the v2 version have much more options and information (at least with regards to permissions) - like when sending the Permissions: [list API command](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) in v3 there is no email address (and lots of other information) in the response - while the [same command in v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/list) is so much detailed.

This is the result in v3:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "id": "XXXXXXXX",
 "type": "user",
 "role": "writer"
},
```

And this is the same one from v2:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "etag": "\"FPnnpOmsqafIS6eGxQncO9NCNYg\"",
 "id": "XXXXXXXX",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/XXXXXXXX/permissions/XXXXXXXX",
 "name": "פסיפס הרצאות",
 "emailAddress": "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com",
 "domain": "gmail.com",
 "role": "writer",
 "type": "user",
 "deleted": false
},
```

1. So my first question - Is there a reason not to use v2? will it get deprecated? and why when using v3 the result is do lacking compering to v2? (I have read several previous posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846293/value-attribute-for-permissions-resource-not-populated-in-responses), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148021/any-way-to-get-email-address-from-google-drive-api-permissions-so-i-can-differen/44052226) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576885/get-google-drive-file-owner-email-address-using-google-drive-api-v3-via-python) and I understand that this is because of privacy issues - but still I find it strange since via the GUI I can get the information without a problem.
2. If I want to use v3 to be on the safe side - how can I use the collaborator email address?
   In v2 I could use [Permissions: getIdForEmail](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/getIdForEmail) but there is no such way in v3.

If I understand right the permissionId is permanent per user - So if I get it once and store it I will be able to translate the collaborators email address to his permissionId without calling the API - right?

Now If I try to do it via version 2 - I guess this is the way to do it:

- `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/permissionIds/email` to get the `permissionIds` for a spesific email
- `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files` to get a list of all the files and the relevant `fileId`

How can I make sure this GET request will go over all of my files and folders? as far as I can see now I only get 100 results but I have more files and folders then that.

Also is there a way to add to this request the permissionIds I got from the first step to I will get a list of the relevant files only?

- `DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions/permissionId` to combain the 2 reasults (the 1st one got me the `permissionIds` from the email and the 2nd got me the `fileId`).

This is the right way to do it with v2? Is there any better way to remove collaborators from any drive sharing (files or folders)?

Now what about v3?

- I see no way to get the `permissionIds` via the collaborator email address.
- I can  lists all the files by using `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`

But again - How can I make sure this GET request will go over all of my files and folders? as far as I can see now I only get 100 results but I have more files and folders then that.

- The delete looks the same: `DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions/permissionId`

But I do need the `permissionId`

To sum it all up:

1. Should I use v2 or v3?
2. What is the best way to remove collaborators permissions so they will not have access to my files and folders on google drive.

Regards,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

#### To address your points

> 1. So my first question - Is there a reason not to use v2? will it get deprecated? and why when using v3 the result is do lacking comparing to v2

Well, first of all, Drive API v3 provides an optimized performance and it also reduces API behavior complexity compared to its preceding version. Unless you plan on using the `apps` collection in the future for your application, it is recommended that you use the v3 version. The most notable improvements are the following:

- Searches for files and shared drives do not return full resources by default, only a subset of commonly used `fields` get returned.
- Almost all methods that return a response now require the `fields` parameter.
- All update operations use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`.
- Readers and commenters can't view permissions.
- The `me` alias for permissions is gone.

**If you check the response of the `permissions.list` request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions
```

This is the response body returned:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permissionList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "permissions": [
    permissions Resource
  ]
}
```

Where the `permissions Resource` looks like this:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "id": string,
  "type": string,
  "emailAddress": string,
  "domain": string,
  "role": string,
  "view": string,
  "allowFileDiscovery": boolean,
  "displayName": string,
  "photoLink": string,
  "expirationTime": datetime,
  "teamDrivePermissionDetails": [
    {
      "teamDrivePermissionType": string,
      "role": string,
      "inheritedFrom": string,
      "inherited": boolean
    }
  ],
  "permissionDetails": [
    {
      "permissionType": string,
      "role": string,
      "inheritedFrom": string,
      "inherited": boolean
    }
  ],
  "deleted": boolean
}
```

**Therefore, the fields you are interested can be retrieved from the request response, but you will have to specify them explicitly when making the request.**

Let's say you are interested in retrieving all the fields available for each permission: in order to do so, you will have to supply the `*` to the `fields` parameter when making the request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=*
```

For a more extensive guide on how to use the `fields` and the correct syntax when making a request, I suggest you check the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter).

> 2. If I want to use v3 to be on the safe side - how can I use the collaborator email address? In v2 I could use `Permissions: getIdForEmail` but there is no such way in v3.

There is indeed no method in Drive v3 for this; however, there is currently an open issue on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759923). What you can do in this situation is to star the issue and eventually add a comment mentioning that you are interested in it and that it would be of use to your application.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 versus v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v3versusv2);
- [Drive API v3 Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list);
- [Drive API v3 Permissions resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource);
- [Return specific fields for a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter).

Comment: Hi @ale13 Thanks for your help and answer. I tried to use the `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=*`
 via the Try this API and I'm getting " "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: fileId.""  What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Replace `fileId` with the actual id of your file.

Comment: Sorry - I guess I lot you. If I need to provide the fileId it means that in order to delete the permissions I need to do 2 calls -  The first one is  to get all the fileIds that a certian email have premissons to and the second one to delete all of those premetions - right? so the first call will be `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/permissions?fields="emailAddress": test@test.com&"role": writers OR readers` (I guess this is not the way to write it) and

Comment: then I should take the permissionId and the fileIds from the result and to a `DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions/permissionId` on them? Can you please give me the relevant commands to do the get by email address so I will be able to get all the files and folders a certain email  is sheared with and then to delete the permissions?

Comment: Or maybe there is one command that will fo the delete without the need to give the fileid or the permissionId and will use the email directly.

Comment: The `permissions.list` will return a list of all the permissions for a specific file, hence the `fileId` parameter which needs to be supplied. If you want to remove certain permissions for the file with the same `fileId`, you need the ids of the permissions you want removed (you get the ids from the previous `permissions.list` request). You cannot achieve this with a single request.

Comment: Thanks again. So the fist step is to try and get all the fileId that a certain email have permissions to - right? what is this command? I guess it's some kind of variation on:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`
When adding `?fields=*` I can see parameters like `"role": "writer"` or  `"role": "reader"` and also the `"emailAddress": "email@gmail.com"`  how can I add to the above commands a query parameters for the role writer and role reader (so it will be writer OR reader) and also the relevant emailAddress also?

Comment: I understand that I can send a GET request like that: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(id,name,description,mimeType,parents,trashed,permissions)` and to get the relevant information - but how can I filter the request to search only for specific mimeType or specific permissions? I want to send such a request and to get back all the files ID of the files and folders that have the  "emailAddress" and  "role" ("owner" OR "reader") I'm looking for. and also the permissionId so I will be able to send a delete request.

Comment: I see here that there is an option to do batch requests - maybe this is relevant? 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing#change_multiple_permissions_with_batch_requests

Comment: That is an option, but you will still need the `permissionId` and the `fileId` as this request handles multiple permissions for a single file.